# PDF generated using TCPDF library doesn't print in adobe acrobat reader but works in preview

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, acrobat

I am using TCPDF library version: 6.3.2 (https://tcpdf.org/about/)

The pdf looks fine and exports as expected.

When I used Preview to view the file and print it works completely fine.

However, when using Adobde Acrobat Reade, I am still able to view the file but unable to print them. When attempting to print it shows the following Errors:

```
'The document could not be printed' -> first pop up error
'There were no pages selected to print' -> followed by the first error
```

[image]

[image]

I am also using `$pdf->ImageSVG` to render charts (https://www.goat1000.com/svggraph.php)

Things I have tried:

1. Added `ob_start();`  before the script starts and added `ob_end_clean();` right before `$pdf->Output('thepdf.pdf', 'I');`

```
    // $this->Image($image_file, 10, 10, 15, '', 'PNG');
    // $this->Image($image_file, 10, 5, 70, 25, 'PNG', '', 'T', true, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);

    $this->Image('@'.file_get_contents('pdf-logonew.jpg'),10,6,60,20);
    
    

    $html = '<h1 style="color:#d40b30; font-size:20px;">'.POST_NAME.'</h1>';
    

    $html_date = '<p style="margin-top:-10px;color:#3E3E3E;font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;">'.PDF_DATE.'</p>';

             
    $this->writeHTMLCell(
        $w=0,
        $h=0,
        $x=0,
        $y=15,
        $html,
        $border=0,
        $ln=0,
        $fill=false,
        $reseth=true,
        $align='R'
    );

    $this->writeHTMLCell(
        $w=0,
        $h=0,
        $x=0,
        $y=23,
        $html_date,
        $border=0,
        $ln=0,
        $fill=false,
        $reseth=true,
        $align='R'
    );

    // $pdf->SetTextColor(255, 255, 255);
    // $this->SetTextColor(255,0,0);
}

    public function Footer() {
        // Position at 15 mm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-20);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);
        // Page number
        // $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
        // $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'R', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
    
        if ($this->page == 1){
        $footertext = '<hr style="color:#BDBDBD;background-color:transparent;"><p style="text-align:right;background-color:white;">Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages().'</p>';
        $this->writeHTML($footertext, false, true, false, true);

        }else{
            $footertext = '<hr style="color:#BDBDBD;background-color:transparent;"><p style="text-align:right;background-color:#e1e8ec;">Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages().'</p>';
        $this->writeHTML($footertext, false, true, false, true);
        }

    }
}
define ('PDF_MARGIN_TOP', 200);

// $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// convert TTF font to TCPDF format and store it on the fonts folder
// $fontname = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('Metropolis-Regular.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 96);

// use the font
// $pdf->SetFont('metropolisfont', '', 14, '', false);
// set document information
// $pdf->SetFont('times', '', 44);
$pdf->SetFont('metropolisfont', '', 44);
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
$pdf->SetTitle(POST_NAME);
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');


// set default header data
// $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 001', PDF_HEADER_STRING, array(0,64,255), array(0,64,128));
// $pdf->SetHeaderData('pdf-logo.png', '70', $post_title, '', array(0,64,255), array(0,64,128));
// $pdf->setFooterData(array(0,64,0), array(0,64,128));
$pdf->setFooterData(array(0,64,0), array(0,64,128));

// set header and footer fonts
// $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
// $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
// $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);

$pdf->SetHeaderMargin('100');
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set default font subsetting mode
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

// Set font
// dejavusans is a UTF-8 Unicode font, if you only need to
// print standard ASCII chars, you can use core fonts like
// helvetica or times to reduce file size.
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 14, '', true);


// Add a page
// This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
$pdf->AddPage();


$description_html = '<div class="container" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;border: 0.25pt solid CutContour;border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;"><p style="font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;line-height:16px;color:#3E3E3E;text-align:left;margin-bottom:0px;">Strategy Description - '.POST_NAME.'</p><p style="font-size:10px;text-align:left;line-height:13px;color:#404040;">'.STRATEGY_DESCRIPTION.'<p></div>';

$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, 80, 23, $description_html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);

$pdf->ImageSVG('@' . $graph_output, $x=80, $y=105, $w=$graph_width, $h=$graph_height, $link='#', $align='', $palign='', $border=0, $fitonpage=true);

$pdf_name = POST_NAME." ".PDF_DATE;


$pdf_name =  str_replace(' - ',' ',$pdf_name);
// $pdf->Output($pdf_name.'.pdf', 'I');
// $pdf->Output('newnewsample'.'.pdf', 'I');
// $pdf->Output($new_custom_pdf_name.'.pdf', 'I');

ob_end_clean(); 
$pdf->Output($pdf_name.'.pdf', 'I');
exit();
```

**This is an update**
So I have tracked down what is causing the issue `$pdf->ImageSVG()` seems to be the problem, I am able to print the PDF in acrobat reader when I remove this, now I am looking into the `ImgSVG()` and see how I can make it work

Comment: Does it print from another viewer? Adobe is not always compatible to PDF specs.

Comment: Hi @MartinZeitler,
yes I tried it with Mac's "Preview" application, it works completely fine and i'm able to print the document without any issues

Comment: `$pdf->ImageSVG()` is causing the issue, when I remove it the PDF prints fine in Acrobat Reader

Answer (score 0):

Try this one It worked for me definitely it will be helpful for you.

You need to add a variable before the source SVG variable and remove # symbol from the `$link` parameter. New code are given below:

```php
$pdf->ImageSVG($file='@' . $graph_output, $x=80, $y=105, $w=$graph_width, $h=$graph_height, $link='', $align='', $palign='', $border=0, $fitonpage=true);
```